# Possible C/C++ compiler bug in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

The following C or C++ code should have as output "11,11,11,"
however using Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5) the output is "11,0,0,"! This only occurs in a release build, and disappears when optimization is turned off. Is this a compiler bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A[100] = { 0 };
    int row = 0;   // BUG disappears if we make this const or short or char...
    int ncols = 3; // BUG disappears if we make this const or short or char...

    for (int y = row; y <= row; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < ncols; ++x)
        {
            const int index = y * ncols + x;

            //A[index] = 11;           // (no bug !)
            *(A + index) = 11;       // BUG!!!
            //*(A + y*ncols+x) = 11;   // (no bug !)
            //*(A + (y*ncols+x)) = 11; // BUG!!!
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < ncols; ++x)
    {
        printf("%d,", A[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in MSVC 2015. Is this the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem?

Comment: I fail to reproduce the claimed behavior with Visual C++ 2015 update 3.

Comment: @WeatherVane Checking on VS 2013.

Comment: @yellowantphil Compiling as C or as C++ both gave the same behavior,

Comment: @yellowantphil The last few editions should have become much better with C99 support.

Comment: Just wanted to say, running this through -O2 on clang 3.9.1 (I know, unrelated to the question, but I was curious) yields a [pretty funny asm result](http://pastebin.com/SMW3Wb6x). Whoever the team is that did their loop analysis should be proud =)

Comment: Tested on both VS15 and VS13, both as cpp and c. Each time the output is what is expected. Could you maybe provide us with the exact build number of the compiler. The generated assembly would also be fun to look at.

Comment: @yellowantphil: I don't know why you were annoyed. VS2013 had rather extensive core language support for C99, especially by Update 5.

Comment: VS2013 Update 5 does indeed exhibit this bug in Release mode in both x64 and Win32 configurations. Exactly as the OP described.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya I have this:Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
    Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.6.01038
    Visual C++ 2013   06177 - 004 - 0447006 - 02743

Comment: Off topic: `for (int y = row; y <= row; ++y)` looks wacky. Give you one iteration, but there are clearer ways to write this. I assume this is an artifact of forcing the bug?

Comment: @user4581301 I know..., but the bug is also there if you have more than 1 iterations. I just wanted to show a "minimal" example.

Comment: @Weather Vane, Yes this definitely is the minimal illustration of the problem that I could make, and please note that the question is not about VS 2015

Comment: @AvD after that became clear, I upvoted your question. Those accusing a compiler of having a bug must be very sure of their ground, since the bug is usually in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be a compiler bug. In Win32 version of the code the compiler uses register `esi` to represent `y` and register `edx` to represent `x`. As @Ajay Brahmakshatriya correctly noted in the comments, it appears that the compiler performed an attempt to exchange the cycles (swap the outer with the inner), but ended up with incorrect code. The very last conditional jump instruction, which is supposed to represent the [exchanged] inner cycle, for some reason transfers control to a location that checks `esi` as well. That check ends iterations prematurely.

```
0018206B  xor         esi,esi             ; This is `y`
0018206D  xor         edx,edx             ; This is `x`
...
00182070  test        esi,esi  
00182072  jg          main+5Ch (018209Ch) ; Exit from the outer cycle?

00182074  lea         eax,[edx+esi*2]     ; Recalculate the starting storage location
00182077  add         eax,esi             ; for the next cycle:
00182079  lea         ecx,[A]             ; eax = esi * 3 + edx
0018207F  lea         eax,[ecx+eax*4]     ; eax = &A[eax]
...
00182082  mov         ecx,1               ; It is not exactly clear to me what this is 
00182087  sub         ecx,esi             ; supposed to do, but when `esi` is `0`, it 
00182089  add         esi,ecx             ; leaves `ecx` as 1, which is correct 
                                          ; number of iterations for outer cycle
...
00182090  mov         dword ptr [eax],0Bh ; Storing the value
00182096  lea         eax,[eax+0Ch]       ; Updating the pointer for the next storage location 
00182099  dec         ecx  
0018209A  jne         main+50h (0182090h) ; Outer cycle [exchanged]

0018209C  inc         edx  
0018209D  cmp         edx,3  
001820A0  jl          main+30h (0182070h) ; Inner cycle [exchanged]: for some reason it
                                          ; jumps to `test esi,esi`, which is what
                                          ; suddenly terminates the iterations
```

Comment: Also the fact that it is adding 12 to eax instead of 4 hints that the constant evaluation considers y to be 1 instead of 0.

Comment: BTW to me it appears that it has performed a loop interchange. It is the outer loop that is being executed 3 times. The inner loop(of y) is being executed one time correctly. But the y is just taking the wrong value.

Comment: can I ask you to print some more values from A? I suspect it is going to print 11,0,0,11,0,0,11,0,0.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: Yes, it is adding 12 for the same reason: some how it believes that inner cycle should not iterate. So it prepares for the next iteration of the outer cycle. It just makes no sense.

Comment: No, I think it does realize that the inner loop is going to execute once. But it just assumes the wrong value for y. Instead of assuming 0 it assumes 1.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, No, when I print 9 values I get 11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, when I execute the outer loop 3 times, the inner loop is always executed only 1 time, so then I do get 11,0,0,11,0,0,11,0,0

Comment: So there are multiple bugs here. The unnecessary checking of esi for no reason which causes the loop to terminate and the improper calculation of the offsets into A (should be eax +=4 instead on 12).

Comment: Wow, they screwed up really bad.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: The +=12 apparently comes from the fact that this is the original *outer* cycle, which is supposed to skip 12 bytes every iteration (if it were to make more than 1). I omitted the code that re-calculated the value of `eax` before each run of inner disassembly cycle. That recalculation makes it correct (i.e. justifies +=12). I re-included that code now.

Comment: That makes sense. I was confused because I couldn't see the recalculation code. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I was most surprised that A[index] and *(A+index) behave differently. Shouldn't the parser already guarantee identical behavior?

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya, about the compiler version: I use the same compiler as you: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86`. But do not forget to optimize for speed /O2 if you want to see the bug...

Comment: @AvD, oh yes! Also similar result on Win64 too. Just a change of registers.